# Parse error when updating user info with currentUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, save

I am trying to update a custom column (`@"matches"`) for `[PFUser currentUser]` however I am receiving this error:

`PFKeychainStore failed to set object for key 'currentUser', with error: -34018`

...using this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        NSLog(@"there is a current user");

       [currentUser setObject:matchesNumber.text forKey:@"matches"];

       [currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
           if (!error) {
               // The currentUser saved successfully.
           } else {
               // There was an error saving the currentUser.
           }
       }];
       } else {
           [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"pfuser"] password:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"pfpass"]
               block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                   if (user) {
                       NSLog(@"user logged in");

                      [user setObject:matchesNumber.text forKey:@"matches"];

                      [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                      if (!error) {
                          // The currentUser saved successfully.
                      } else {
                          // There was an error saving the currentUser.
                      }
                  }];
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"login failed");
                      // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                  }
              }];
          }
```

I figure the redundancy can't hurt, and I updated my Parse SDK to make sure that wasn't the problem, as for a few other people, it was. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of object is matchesNumber? Why are you using matchesNumber.text ?

Comment: @LonelyPenguin matchesNumber is a UILabel.

Comment: @LonelyPenguin maybe it is not correct to use `setObject` with a string...but I also tried with `setValue` and I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug in Parse. See if you can find similarities in this issue: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/437

Comment: I noticed that, while the error happens, it does not affect the storing of data on parse, so I am just going to ignore the problem for now.